# Partial View click event not fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-load

My *.aspx Page (main page):

```
function getEmployeeHours(employeeId,year,month) {
 $('#clocked-details').load('/Employees/GetEmployeeClockedHours/',{ 'employeeId': employeeId,'year': year,'month': month });
    };
```

My partial view *.ascx :

```
 <td>
   <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="actionButton">
     Save</button>
  </td>
```

As above code snippet I need to accsess partial view **btnSave** from main view to trigger click event.

I have written below code inside the main view.

```
$('#btnSave').off('click').on('click', function () {

         var yearValue = $("#year").val();
         var monthValue = $("#month").val();

         $.ajax({
             url: "/Employees/UpdateEmployeeClockedHoursByProvider",
             type: 'POST',
             cache: false,
             data: { employeeId: employeeId, year: yearValue, month: monthValue },
             success: function (result) {

             },
             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 alert(xhr.status);
                 alert(thrownError);
             }
         });

         return false;
     });
```

But it doesn't fire.Here I am using **load** jquery method to load my partial view asynchronously.

So my question is how should I fire click event of partial view ?

Comment: Is the button click event inside partial view or the main view?

Comment: @SivaGopal I have put that event both places.But no luck ?Any Idea ?

Comment: Did you try ("#btnSave").live("click") event of jquery as well while keeping the script in the main view?

Comment: @SivaGopal Thanks. It's working for live method.If you can put this as a answer then I can accept it.

Comment: thanks for the update and i provided it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the usercontrol containging the button is being loaded dynamically, you can use `("#btnSave").live("click"){...}` event of jquery while keeping the script in the main view, which can keep track of the controls being added to the DOM in future. So whenever a control matching the specified selector for "live(..)" appears, the event is wiredup automatically.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I tried this and got 'TypeError: $(...).live is not a function'. Maybe .live is not supported anymore ?

Answer (score 22):

Since your html is being loaded into the page dynamically you'll have to give more context to your `DOM` query.

Try this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#bntSave', function(){
  //do stuff
});
```