# How to write a client side custom java script for validation in partial view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a custom java script for validation in my partial view. I am displaying my partial view using a Pop-up.

To Display my Partial View as a Pop-up, I am doing this.

```
  <a href="#" title="Genrate Purchase Order" class="btn btn-success genratepo" onclick="GenratePO(@item.Id)"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></a>

<script>
     function GenratePO(orderId) {
         debugger;
         var url = "/Order/GenratePO?OrderId=" + orderId;

                 $("#myModalBody").load(url, function (data) {
                     $("#myModalBody").html(data);
                     $("#myModal").modal("show");
                 });
             }
```

> After that I am returning my partial view through controller

```
if(orderId < 1)
        {
            ShowAlert("Invalid Id or Record Deleted",AlertStyle.Danger);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var orderpreferenceData= _unitOfWork.OrderPreference.FindBy(m => m.OrderDetailId == orderId && m.IsDeleted != true && m.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault();
        var viewModel = new PurchaseOrderViewModel()
        {
            OrderId = orderId,
            VendorList = GetVendorSelectList(),
            FabricList = GetFabricSelectList(),
            FabricId = Convert.ToInt32(orderpreferenceData.FabricId)
        };
        return PartialView("GenratePO",viewModel);
```

> But when i am trying to write my custom java script method in partial view It is not invoking.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert("hello");
         $("#btn_Submit").click(function () {

             debugger;
             var selectedindex = $(".ddlVendor").prop('selectedIndex');

             if (selectedindex < 0) {
                 $(".lblmsg").text("Select Vendor First");
             }
             var orderQuantity = $(".txtOrderQuantity").val();

             if (!jQuery.trim(orderQuantity).length > 0) {
                 $(".lblmsg").text("Please Enter Order Quantity");
             }

         });

     });
```

> I didn't know why this is happening and the java script is not working.

Comment: How it is not working? Any errors in browser console?

Comment: No. errors in browser console. I also tried to write the custom java script in page from where i am calling my partial view but no luck.

Comment: To troubleshoot , Try your java script validation without partial view , I mean in main view.

Comment: Are you able to hit "/Order/GenratePO?OrderId=" + orderId;"
from first JavaScript?

Comment: @SahilSharma yes. everything is working fine , except the client side custom validation part. The validation part is not working.

Comment: @Bhupendra Try the posted answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: `btn_Submit` is of type `submit` and is it within form tag?

Comment: I have solved this issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, for second JavaScript try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
             alert("hello");

             $("#btn_Submit").on('click', function () {
                 alert("hello again");  //Just to check if it is working or not
                 debugger;
                 var selectedindex = $(".ddlVendor").prop('selectedIndex');

                 if (selectedindex < 0) {
                     $(".lblmsg").text("Select Vendor First");
                 }
                 var orderQuantity = $(".txtOrderQuantity").val();

                 if (!jQuery.trim(orderQuantity).length > 0) {
                     $(".lblmsg").text("Please Enter Order Quantity");
                 }

             });

         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the content of your partial view is dynamically added into your `DOM` , 
so the dynamic elements are not registered with your `Javascript click` function, 
to make your `click` work you can use `Jquery` [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert("hello");
     $(document).on('click', '#btn_Submit', function(){
         alert("click works");
             debugger;
             var selectedindex = $(".ddlVendor").prop('selectedIndex');

             if (selectedindex < 0) {
                 $(".lblmsg").text("Select Vendor First");
             }
             var orderQuantity = $(".txtOrderQuantity").val();

             if (!jQuery.trim(orderQuantity).length > 0) {
                 $(".lblmsg").text("Please Enter Order Quantity");
             }

         });

     });


</script>
```

If you are using Jquery validation plugin with MVC then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135013/2218697) post.

Refrences:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484295/jquery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437007/partial-view-click-event-not-fire)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myModal").on("submit", "form", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      debugger;
        var selectedindex = $(".ddlVendor").prop('selectedIndex');

        if (selectedindex < 0) {
            $(".lblmsg").text("Select Vendor First");
        }
        var orderQuantity = $(".txtOrderQuantity").val();

        if (!jQuery.trim(orderQuantity).length > 0) {
            $(".lblmsg").text("Please Enter Order Quantity");
        }
    });
});
```

> And to make this work i have to write my java script in the page from where i am calling my Partial View.